# Not a duplicate of what was pointed and closed for

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

My question at https://superuser.com/questions/351055/test-for-protection-softwares was closed and said to be a duplicated. I have checked the given links, they were not only superficial to the matter as they don't cover 1/10 of the question it self.

What do I do in order to have it reopened ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing. I am going to quote from the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) under What not to ask here:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

So in short, we can close it as a duplicate, or as off topic. The duplicate at least gave you options for further research, but if you choose, we can re-close it as off topic.

Comment: then do re-close it as off topic if that is the case as current it doesn't look helpful at all as a duplicate. Best regards.

Comment: Diago mentions why I chose to close it as Dupe instead of plain offtopic - to give you a small pointer. If you want it to be closed as off topic, so be it. @Prix